# Laravel Custom Schedule

Tags: php, laravel

Helllo,

Laravel have ways to schedule commands using these methods which they provided in the documentation at [Laravel Schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options). So I'm stuck on how to write a custom schedule for example I have schedules which need to run every 3hrs and other every 6hrs. Can I get a link to a tutorial about this or some info on how to go about this.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use following tutorials for cron schedule:
https://appdividend.com/2018/03/01/laravel-cronjob-scheduling-tutorial/
https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-task-scheduling-with-cron-job-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel gives you the option to specify the schedule on a cron. In which case, you can use the following for your case.

**3 Hours**

`->cron('0 */3 * * *')`

**6 Hours**

`->cron('0 */6 * * *')`

I would also recommend learning about different cron rules, if you like.